# No InfoPath forms in SP 2013 workflows?

Tags: workflow, infopath, 2013

I just read [here](http://sharepointdragons.com/2012/10/11/no-more-infopath-forms-in-sharepoint-2013-workflows/), that InfoPath forms will no longer be used in Workflows.  Is there something that will replace InfoPath? or are forms in the Workflows just going away?

Thanks!

Comment: I am by no means a SharePoint expert. In fact, I first became aware of the existence of SharePoint about three months ago. However, I'm simply wondering if there is perhaps a slight confusion concerning "Workflow forms". Is this not the form automatically generated when a workflow is created that is used to manually start the workflow, and is not linked to InfoPath forms that is published to a SharePoint list or library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably one should use references from Microsoft itself on MS products.

So, Microsoft source tells:

- **"Workflow form changed from InfoPath form to aspx form**
  For a workflow based on SharePoint Designer 2013 (WF4) and Windows Azure Workflow, SharePoint creates aspx forms instead of InfoPath forms that were created by SharePoint Designer 2010 (WF3.5) workflows.

  Workaround
  **No workaround is available. If you want to customize the form, you can click it from Forms in workflow summary page and a generic aspx page editor appears**."
  Cited from:
  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/sharepoint-server-2013-known-issues-HA102919021.aspx

That would have been strange to use client-oriented Infopath for sharepoint workflows when it is impossible even to install Office 2013 in Windows XP.

As such Infopath was already barely supported. For example, VSTA (Visual Studio Tools for Applications) form Office 2010 is no more than Visual Studio 2005, with no more than .NET 2.0 with serious bugs migrated untouched from Office 2007.

And had serious self-contradictory idiosyncrasies like impossibility to develop purely local (isolated) Infopath apps with external connections or code-behind without attributing them Full Trust and digitally signing them, etc.

In other words, client-based Infopath approach to server-side sharepoint workflows was rather a conceptual and architectural Microsoft error long time ago. Client-based applications should be client-based and server application should be server-based. There is no sense to mix them.

Answer (score 5):

Just came back from the SharePoint 2012 conference in Vegas.  I asked this at the MS developer booth and was told to 'read between the lines.'  My take is yes, there is no more InfoPath in SharePoint 2013.  I plan to write more in a blog in a few days.

Article: http://surfpointtech.com/2012/11/15/notes-from-the-edge-sharepoint-2012-conference-las-vegas/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is Good as coded Infopath seems not running well in sharepoint 2010.
I have tried code VSTA in InfoPath 2010 to Form Library in Sharepoint 2010 but has error always.

http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/t/18834.aspx
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationlegacy/thread/7d937195-24df-40a7-97eb-b40c551ae3d3/